# How to prevent squashing flexbox absolute pane by ChartJs?

Tags: css, flexbox, chart.js, css-position, absolute

The code below is simplified version of actual one, but it "correctly" shows the problem -- I have window with T-layout. Top section with toolbar, and below the left with some long content, and the right which should take the remaining space.

I used "absolute" position for the left pane because my first problem was how to scroll long content within pane, this is what I found, so I used it.

On the right there is ChartJs and initially it really takes the remaining space but if I move the mouse over it refreshes the content, resulting in squashing the left pane to zero.

How to prevent it (not using hardcoded sizes, like "min-width: 200px")? As left-right panes sizing goes, my intention is "left -- take all what is necessary, right -- take the rest".

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: pink; overflow:hidden;margin:0" onload="starter()">
    <div style="display: flex;flex-direction:column; height: 100vh;width: 100%">
        <!-- TOOLBAR -->
        <div style="flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0;">
            <button>hello</button>
        </div>

        <div style="flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 1;   
                            display: flex;flex-direction:row; ">

            <!-- LEFT PANE -->
            <div  style="position:relative; background-color: aqua; overflow:scroll;
                         flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 1;">
                <div style="position:absolute; width: 100%">
                    <div>
                        <h1>
                                <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>4</li>
                                <li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>1</li>
                                <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>4</li>
                                <li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li><li>0</li>
                            </ul>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div>left</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- RIGHT PANE -->
            <div style="background-color: green; flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 1;
                        display: flex;flex-direction:column;">

                <div style="position: relative;flex-shrink: 1; flex-grow: 1;">
                    <canvas id="bar-chart" style="" ></canvas>
                </div>

                <div style="flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0;">right</div>
        
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
    function starter(){
        // https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/
        new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
                datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Population (millions)",
                    backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
                    data: [2478,5267,734,784,433]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio : false,
                legend: { display: false },
                title: {  
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
                }
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started from the initial problem -- how to take remaining space and enable scroll there? For two panes there is nice solution with the flex layout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68516470/210342 but as in my case, when I have nested panes, I couldn't make flex take entire window and only window space (without using this hack with absolute position).

Since I don't know CSS I tried grid approach and it worked right on spot. I simply added "height:100vh" for entire grid container and for given scrollable pane "overflow:auto" and that's it.

Now I have scrolling and well sized chart.

Nice grid generator I used: https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/